# Regex find and replace with gulp / node and use part of the find's string in the replace?

Tags: javascript, node.js, gulp

Im performing a find and replace with gulp.

I need to find this string below (ANYTHING can be anything, its not a string of 'ANYTHING'):

```
{% id_ANYTHING %}
```

And replace it with this:

```
{% block ANYTHING %}{% endblock %}
```

**Example1.**

Replace this:

```
{% id_page %}
```

With this:

```
{% block page %}{% endblock %}
```

**Example2.**

Replace this:

```
{% id_whatever %}
```

With this:

```
{% block whatever %}{% endblock %}
```

Ive found the regex that I need to find the match. Im already using gulp-replace for a similar but simpler task so Ive started using it for this but I'm not sure how to grab the 'anything' value so that I can use it in the replace.

https://github.com/lazd/gulp-replace

```
replace = function() {
  return gulp.src('before.html')
    .pipe(replace({
      patterns:
        [{
          match: /{% id_.{2,99} %}/g,
          replacement: '{% block page %}{% endblock %}'
        }]
    }))
    .pipe(gulp.dest('after.html'));
},
```

Should I be looking to do this with Gulp or Node?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Per the docs for [`gulp-replace`](https://github.com/lazd/gulp-replace#replacement-1) you can use a function for the replacement value, just like you can for [`String.prototype.replace()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace#Specifying_a_function_as_a_parameter)

Also, I've modified your RegEx to group the `.{2,99}` together using `()`. The `String.replace()` callback function will breakout each group as a separate arg. Since you're only interested in extracting that group, we can have `String.replace()` do all the work and return back the value to replace the matched text.

```
const gulp = require('gulp')
const replace = require('gulp-replace');
const path = require('path');
let pattern = new RegExp(/{% id_(.{2,99}) %}/, 'g');

gulp.task('replace', () => {
  return gulp.src('before.html')
    .pipe(replace(pattern, (match, p1) => {
      return `{% block ${p1} %} {% endblock %}`;
    }))
    .pipe(gulp.dest(path.join(__dirname, 'after.html')));
});
```

Comment: Should this: let pattern = new RegExp(/{% id_(.{2,99}) %}/, 'g'); 

In fact be this?: let pattern = new RegExp('{% id_(.{2,99}) %}', 'g'); 

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions

Comment: @Evans They're interchangeable. If you use `''` around your expression than you don't need the `//` around the expression. You can use `//` as an actual literal though when you pass it in to a RegExp. [See here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp#Description). Just to note though, if you use `''` around your expression you'll need to still follow escape rules for strings where as with the literal notation using `//` you don't need to worry about that.